# Two keyboards on the kiosk mode

Tags: windows, keyboard, tablet, kiosk

I have a problem with appearing two keyboard when I use tablet in kiosk mode. I see black and gray keyboard (browser - edge). I don't really know why it's happening and I wanna turn off gray keyboard. I have such changes in registry editior:

[image: here are settings]

[image: here is keyboards photo]

Comment: To turn off the Windows on-screen keyboard, disable the Windows Service `Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service`. See Touch https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-disable-the-on-screen-touch-keyboard-in-windows-10 . *Hopefuly., that will leave the gay keyboard active.*